# Map Data Based off ID

Tags: reactjs

If i'm using the map function, how would you limit it by ID, e.g I only want to map ID 1,2 out of 3 possible datapoints?

What's the industry standard solution?

```
export const userInputs = [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: "First Name",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Remy",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: "Surname",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Sharp",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        label: "Email",
        type: "email",
        placeholder: "remysharp@gmail.com",
    }
];
```

Mapping like this, for email, i'd only like name and surname to be mapped inputs.

```
              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <FormInput className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <UserInput type={input.type} placeholder={input.placeholder} />
                </FormInput>
              ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for` loop.

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const useInputs = [
    /*...*/
  ]
  const limit = 2

  const userInputDomList = []

  for (let i = 0; i < userInputs.length; i++) {
    if (limit >= i) break
    userInputDomList.push(<div key={userInputs[i].id}> </div>)
  }

  return <section>{userInputDomList}</section>
}
```

you could use `.filter` or `.map` for same result but it will loop over all elements instead of stopping at `limit` index.

For id based selection

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  const useInputs = [
    /*...*/
  ]

  const userInputDomList = []

  // using for loop
  /* for (let i = 0; i < userInputs.length; i++) {
    const id = userInputs[i].id
    if (id === 3) {
      userInputDomList.push(<div key={id}> </div>)
      break
    }
  } */

  // using for..of
  for (const userInput of userInputs) {
    if (userInput.id === 3) {
      userInputDomList.push(<div key={userInput.id}> </div>)
      break
    }
  }

  return <section>{userInputDomList}</section>
}
```

if really want reander only one item to be rendered

```js
function RenderMatchingId({ userInputs, userInputId }) {
  for (const userInput of userInputs) {
    if (userInput.id === userInputId) {
      return <section>found {userInput.id}</section>
    }
  }

  // fallback
  return <section>404 not found</section>
}
```

Comment: thanks bogdanoff, but what if I only wanted to select ID 3? How would you approach this

Comment: @n_d22 I have updated my answer for that. check it